# C# File Relative Path to a class

Tags: c#, class, xslt, namespaces

I have a C# class file which will be packaged as a class library. In the class library project, I have a folder called XSL and inside this folder I have some XSL files. My C# class which does XSL validation is in a different namespace. How can I refer to the XSL folder from a different namespace in which I have the class that wants to do the XSL validation by using the XSL files?

Comment: Libraries don't typically include resources, the executing application that uses your library would contain resources.  However you can embed them if you really need them.  Check out this [MSDN Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)

Comment: Namespaces and file system folders are two very unrelated things.  Generally I imagine the class library would either expose the path as a dependency (a parameter on a method for example) so the consuming application can provide it, and/or allow a config file setting to specify the path, and likely default to the current working directory if no path is provided.

Comment: I have already embedded the XSL files in my class library, but they are in a different folder. All I want to do is to just reference them!

Comment: @user3102968: well - in contrast to Java - an assembly doesn't store class files in an assembly. So there is no such thing as a relative path...

Comment: The folder is irrelevant, especially if it gets embedded.  You'll need to perform some reflection to get the resource streams.  The article I posted above has some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are embedded in the Assembly, you can get their content (`Stream`) using the [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

So:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); //get access to the current assembly.
Stream s = a.GetManifestResourceStream("xslt.file1");
//process stream s
```

In case it is a third party assembly (class library) you can load it by creating an `Assembly` instance from that path:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("file.dll");
```

This of course only works if it is a .NET assembly with a version that can be interpreted. So don't use it to load a `.exe` generated by a C-compiler.

Each resource is stored by a dot-separated path, for instance `"MyCompany.MyProduct.MyDirectory.MyFile.xslt"`